# Count only published videos

Tags: django

I have a Category model and Video model

```
Category:
   name=Charfield()

Video:
   name=CharField()
   category=ManyToManyField()
   is_live=BooleanField()
```

And I want to have the get all categories with a video count but I want to exclude videos who are not live.
This my start state:

```
Category.objects.annotate(video_count=Count('video'))

# I tried this but I'm not sure if this the right way
 Category.objects.exclude(video__is_liive=False)
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the field you are annotating, you need to use raw SQL as you can't do it through the ORM yet. I wrote a blog post about this:

http://timmyomahony.com/blog/filtering-annotations-django/

Your situation is a little more complicated as you have a M2M relationship which uses an intermediate table. You need something like the following which joins all 3 tables and counts only those that are marked `is_live=True` (this is totally untested so you will need to play around with it)

```
categories = Category.objects.all().extra(select = {
  "video_count" : """
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myapp_videocategory
    JOIN myapp_videocategory on myapp_videocategory.category_id = myapp_category.id
    JOIN myapp_video on myapp_videocategory.video_id = myapp_video.id
  WHERE myapp_video.is_live = True
  """
}).order_by("-live_video_count",)
```